# RTL8188ETV not connecting to some networks

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, drivers

I am experimenting with an ESP32, so I purchased a chinese wifi adapter for my desktop computer running archlinux lastest.

Using the RTL8xxxu driver, I can connect to most network... except the ESP32 when any encryption is enabled (like WPA2_PSK) currently.

Disclaimer : I know a thing or two about wifi, but I'm very far from being an expert.

For a simple setup, I forced 20MHz band width, WPA2, PSK.

The only difference with other network I can connect to is that in LinSSID, it shows 'wpa_psk/sha-256' while other network shows only 'wpa_psk'.

Using wireshark on my laptop (which *can* connect to the ESP32 btw), I monitored the frames while trying to connect. I see the beacon, the probe request from the desktop pc, and its response from the ESP, but the desktop retries indefinitely, as if it could not receive / read the response. This hyppothesis is backed up by the message from nmtui : "The Wi-Fi network could not be found"

I also tried other drivers, but I only get worse result (could not connect to my home wifi while RTL8xxxu can).

Any tip on what's going ? Or at least, on how to investigate further ?